# Calculate sort order of pixels on the border of a shape, in Go

Tags: sorting, go, image-processing, pixel

I made this little program that read a PNG file, and find the coordinates of any pixel in the image that is part of the *border* of the shape depicted (code below).

We define here a *"pixel part of the border"* as *"every colored pixel that have a white pixel immediately on top, or at bottom, or on one of its sides"*.

This simple algorithm find the border of a shape and ignore any empty (white) pixel and any non-empty (colored) pixel which constitute the shape *infill*.

What I get is a slice of `Point` with all this pixel's coordinates, printed on screen, but they are naturally sorted by the scanning process who finds them, from top to bottom, and from left to right.

What I wanted to achieve is the border's points being sorted as if they draw a continuos line around the shape, starting on the first border pixel encountered, and progressing in clockwise order around the shape.

So for a square like this (sorry is a very little image):

[image: square1.png]

of 8x8 pixels, in a grid of 10x10 pixel, I get this coordinates:

```
2,2
3,2
4,2
5,2
6,2
7,2
2,3
7,3
2,4
7,4
2,5
7,5
2,6
7,6
2,7
3,7
4,7
5,7
6,7
7,7
```

Or, graphically

[image: whatIGet]

But what I really wanted is this (I have manually sorted this points):

```
2,2
3,2
4,2
5,2
6,2
7,2
7,3
7,4
7,5
7,6
7,7
6,7
5,7
4,7
3,7
2,7
2,6
2,5
2,4
2,3
```

[image: whatIwant]

---

Or, in the case of this little H shape

[image: h1.png]

I get this:

```
2,2
3,2
6,2
7,2
2,3
3,3
6,3
7,3
2,4
4,4
5,4
7,4
2,5
4,5
5,5
7,5
2,6
3,6
6,6
7,6
2,7
3,7
6,7
7,7
```

But I wanted this (also manually sorted):

```
2,2
3,2
3,3
4,4
5,4
6,3
6,2
7,2
7,3
7,4
7,5
7,6
7,7
6,7
6,6
5,5
4,5
3,6
3,7
2,7
2,6
2,5
2,4
2,3
```

I hope to have illustrated well my case. I have tried to think about a solution myself, but I have no idea of how to approach a problem like this. If you have a direct solution or want to point me in the right direction, or to some reading materials about this sort of problems and their solutions, I will be very thankful.

Sorry for my bad english.

This is my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "image"
    "image/png"
    "io"
    "os"
)

var (
    println = fmt.Println
    printf  = fmt.Printf
)

type Pixel struct {
    R int
    G int
    B int
}

type Point struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

func main() {
    imageFilename := "square1.png"

    image.RegisterFormat("png", "png", png.Decode, png.DecodeConfig)

    file, err := os.Open(imageFilename)
    if err != nil {
        println("Error: File could not be opened")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    pixels, err := getPixels(file)
    if err != nil {
        println("Error: Image could not be decoded")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    borders := findBorders(pixels)

    // Sorting the borders points in clockwise order starting from the first encountered point (but how?)
    // borders = sortBorders(borders)

    // Print borders points
    for _, point := range borders {
        printf("%d,%d\n", point.X, point.Y)
    }
}

func findBorders(pixels [][]Pixel) []Point {
    var borders []Point
    for y := 0; y < len(pixels); y++ {
         for x := 0; x < len(pixels[y]); x++ {
              pixel := pixels[y][x]
              if !whitePixel(pixel) {
                  if whitePixel(pixels[y-1][x]) ||
                     whitePixel(pixels[y][x-1]) ||
                     whitePixel(pixels[y+1][x]) ||
                     whitePixel(pixels[y][x+1]) {
                         borders = append(borders, Point{x, y})
                  }
              }
         }
    }
    return borders
}

// Return true if a pixel is white
func whitePixel(pixel Pixel) bool {
     return pixel.R == 255 && pixel.G == 255 && pixel.B == 255
}

// Get the bi-dimensional pixel array
func getPixels(file io.Reader) ([][]Pixel, error) {
    img, _, err := image.Decode(file)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    bounds := img.Bounds()
    width, height := bounds.Max.X, bounds.Max.Y

    var pixels [][]Pixel
    for y := 0; y < height; y++ {
        var row []Pixel
        for x := 0; x < width; x++ {
            row = append(row, rgbaToPixel(img.At(x, y).RGBA()))
        }
        pixels = append(pixels, row)
    }

    return pixels, nil
}

// img.At(x, y).RGBA() returns four uint32 values, we need something a little more comfortable
func rgbaToPixel(r uint32, g uint32, b uint32, a uint32) Pixel {
    return Pixel{int(r / 257), int(g / 257), int(b / 257)}
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I have *almost* found a solution. For the square example if fail at the corners `{7, 7}` and `{2, 7}`, because, in my opinion, when it finds a diagonal neighbor before a vertical or horizontal one, if it comes first in the `unsorted` slice this algorithm thinks it is good enough and *skip* the closest one, who remain ignored. Please take a look:

```golang
func sortBorders(unsorted []Point) []Point {
    original := make([]Point, len(unsorted))
    copy(original, unsorted)
    expected := []Point{{2, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}, {5, 2}, {6, 2}, {7, 2}, {7, 3}, {7, 4}, {7, 5}, {7, 6}, {7, 7}, {6, 7}, {5, 7}, {4, 7}, {3, 7}, {2, 7}, {2, 6}, {2, 5}, {2, 4}, {2, 3}}

    // Finding the first one is easy
    sorted := []Point{unsorted[0]}
    unsorted = unsorted[1:]

    stillUnsorted := func() bool {
        return len(unsorted) > 0
    }

    lastSorted := func() Point {
        return sorted[len(sorted)-1]
    }

    neighbor := func(s, u Point) bool {
        if (s.X == u.X || s.X == u.X+1 || s.X == u.X-1) && (s.Y == u.Y || s.Y == u.Y+1 || s.Y == u.Y-1) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    removeFromUnsorted := func(index int) {
        fresh := unsorted[:index]
        unsorted = append(fresh, unsorted[index+1:]...)
    }

    addToSorted := func(point Point) {
        sorted = append(sorted, point)
    }

    for stillUnsorted() {
        for i, point := range unsorted {
            if neighbor(lastSorted(), point) {
                removeFromUnsorted(i)
                addToSorted(point)

                println("---------")
                println("original:", original)
                println("unsorted:", unsorted)
                println("sorted  :", sorted)
                println("expected:", expected)
                break
            }
        }
    }

    return sorted
}
```

With the square example from above, this produce the following output:

```
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 3} {2 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 3} {2 4} {2 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 3} {2 4} {2 5} {2 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 3} {2 4} {2 5} {2 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {6 7}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 3} {2 4} {2 5} {2 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {6 7} {5 7}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 3} {2 4} {2 5} {2 6} {2 7} {3 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 3} {2 4} {2 5} {2 6} {2 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 3} {2 4} {2 5} {2 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 6}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 3} {2 4} {2 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 6} {2 5}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 3} {2 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
---------
original: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {2 3} {7 3} {2 4} {7 4} {2 5} {7 5} {2 6} {7 6} {2 7} {3 7} {4 7} {5 7} {6 7} {7 7}]
unsorted: [{2 7} {7 7}]
sorted  : [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
expected: [{2 2} {3 2} {4 2} {5 2} {6 2} {7 2} {7 3} {7 4} {7 5} {7 6} {7 7} {6 7} {5 7} {4 7} {3 7} {2 7} {2 6} {2 5} {2 4} {2 3}]
^Csignal: interrupt
```

As the `unsorted` slice never reach the empty status, the execution continue forever...

How can I make this work? Also, how can this be made clearer in code?

Comment: Pick a starting point (e.g. find min x - if more than 1 - find min x & y); find its neighbor (there will be 2 - so pick 1); Find it's neighbor who has not been used (should be 1); continue till all points are exhausted.

Comment: Thanks @colm.anseo but that is not very clear to me, I will think about it

Comment: @colm.anseo with your input I tried to make an algorithm that almost work. Some other suggestions please?

Comment: If it's skipping corner neighbors, ensure you check for a closer neighbor first (up, down, left, right) and if none, then try a diagonal neighbor.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem as yours. I have a little bit search on internet and found not enough  suitable things, so i want to explain my own solution that all options that you wanted them are included here, but notice that the start point is not at our control in this way.

First get start with Open Source Computer Vision library (known as cv2)  that has very nice options. It provide a python command known as "cv2.findContours(1, 2, 3)" which is in my recent works used so much, and i will explain about num options that put in "cv2.findContours" command. Second thing that must pay attention to is this command gives you pixel point coordinates on border of your object, so we found them.

Option 1 is your image, next is hierarchy option which used when you work on multi component shape like sands, hence for a single option i recommend to place "cv2.RETR_LIST" to eliminate additional calculations and avoid complexity. For more information I mentioned the link below to know why i use that.

Link: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html

Third option is a very nice one which it greatly reduces the amount of calculations and i love it. the explanation for your question is that you want "all" the pixel point coordinates ordered clockwise and not an "approximation" of them. So use "cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE" option in third place. To know why i am talking about "approximation" focus on Link below.

Link: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

Now you definitely know how to write the code. The Python code is something like the code:

```
import cv2
Contour, Hierarchy = cv2.findContours(Input_image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

Given that we are working on only one object, to order or "sorting" all points Clockwisely, use the command:

```
Contour[0][::-1]
```

Contour[0] is list of all border points of first contour "Counter-Clockwisely". Cause in this case we have only one contour just use "Contour[0][::-1]" to reverse it. Now all pixel points sorted by their coordinates "Clockwisely", But remember that we did not choose the start point ourselves. to see them as a list use command:

```
for c in Contour[0]:
   print(c[0])
```

We achieve the border's point coordinates that being sorted as if they draw a continuous line around the shape, starting on the first border pixel encountered, and progressing in clockwise order around the shape.

[A Simple Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZOlt.png)